# How to use regex to replace unmatched parentheses in a string with no nested parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this,

```
text  = 'AWS certification ( AWS Solutions Architect'
text1 = 'AWS certification ( AWS Solutions Architect )'
```

how to replace `(` in `text` variable but ignore it in `text1` because in `text1` we have both the parenthesis?

I have tried a basic `re.sub('\(', '-', text)` but this is replacing `(` in both text and text1 which is not what I want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you have nested `(` and `)` in input?

Comment: If the parenthesis can not occur afterwards, you could use a positive lookahead `\((?=[^()\r\n]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/blN5St/1 or a negative lookahead `\((?![^()\r\n]*\))`

Comment: This may have a couple of solutions depending on how many parentheses you may have and what the actual requirements are. If you need to remove all non-matched parentheses (without nested parentheses support), use `re.sub(r'(\([^()]*\))|[()]', lambda x: x.group(1) or "-", text)`, see a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YLPXrq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
text = re.sub(r'(\([^()]*\))|[()]', lambda x: x.group(1) or "-", text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YLPXrq):

```py
import re
texts  = [ 'AWS certification ( AWS Solutions Architect', 'AWS certification ( AWS Solutions Architect )']
for text in texts:
    print( re.sub(r'(\([^()]*\))|[()]', lambda x: x.group(1) or "-", text) )
# => AWS certification - AWS Solutions Architect
#    AWS certification ( AWS Solutions Architect )
```

Here, `(\([^()]*\))|[()]` finds and captures into Group 1 any strings between parentheses having no inner parentheses, and then `[()]` matches either `(` or `)` in any other context. Then, the replacement is either `-` if Group 1 was not matched, else, Group 1 value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any other condition, replace only if opening and closing parenthesis' count is not same.

```
>>> if text.count('(') != text.count(')'):
...   re.sub('\(', '-', text)
...
'AWS certification - AWS Solutions Architect'
```